# Alternatives to spTransfrom function due retirement of rgdal

Tags: r, rgdal

I have a script to filter occurence data from gbif with a shapefile. Due to the retirement of the rgdal/rgeos I have to make some changes.

```
head(sp_gbif)
        lon       lat     gbifID
1 -70.95618 -53.27092 3457120752
2 -68.31865 -54.81420 3031584233
3  22.76239  66.60015 3431642207
4  16.69931  64.20202 3432283190
5  23.32176  66.11418 3432398188
6  22.29740  66.74461 3432398189

shape
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 7.511393, 10.49182, 47.5338, 49.79137  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 6
names       : USE, RS,       RS_ALT,                GEN,       SHAPE_LENG,       SHAPE_AREA 
value       :   2, 08, 080000000000, Baden-WÃ¼rttemberg, 1298891.66320858, 35801397076.4735


#subset the GBIF data into a data frame
occ.map <- data.frame(sp_gbif[["lon"]], sp_gbif[["lat"]], sp_gbif[["gbifID"]])
print(str(occ.map, 1))

#simplify column names
names(occ.map)[1:3] <- c('long', 'lat', 'gbifID')
print(head(occ.map, 10))

#turning the data frame into a "spatial points data frame"
coordinates(occ.map) <- c("long", "lat")

#defining the datum 
proj4string(occ.map) <- crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
crs(shape) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

#reprojecting the 'gbif' data frame to the same as in the 'shape' object

occ.map <- spTransform(occ.map, proj4string(shape))

#Identifying records from gbif that fall within the shape polygons
inside <- occ.map[apply(gIntersects(occ.map, shape, byid = TRUE), 2, any),]

#Prepare data frame for joining with the occcurrence df so only records 
#that fall inside the polygons get selected 
res.gbif <- data.frame(inside@data)
final.gbif <- sp_gbif %>% semi_join(res.gbif, by = "gbifID")
head(final.gbif)
```

I have tried to use sf but sf_transform for example doesn´t work with spatialpointsdataframes.

Has somebody an idea to adjust the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to using `sf` spatial data frames instead of `sp` spatial data frames in order to use `st_transform`.

You construct these with functions like `st_as_sf` to convert from a data frame or `st_read` to read from standard data formats like Shapefiles (although use GeoPackage if you can). Tutorials are online.

The big problem is if you want to call functions in other packages that need `sp` data frames, and haven't been converted to use `sf` class data frames yet. In this case you should try and keep your workflow using `sf` for as much as possible, and then convert from one format to the other when necessary for interoperability:

```
sfdata = st_as_sf(spdata)
spdata = as(sfdata, "Spatial")
```